# jq: join array elements from different files into one array

Tags: arrays, jq

I have a series of JSON files like these:

```
[
  {
    "bent_general": "0",
    "bext_general": "0",
    "date_yyyymmdd": "20171104",
    "end_time": "2017-11-07T02:58:56",
    "householdid": "EAM2231"
  },
  {
    "bent_general": "2",
    "bext_general": "8",
    "date_yyyymmdd": "20171126",
    "end_time": "2017-12-07T05:58:56",
    "householdid": "EAM1234",
  }
]
```

I need to combine them in one big file with the same structure:

```
[
  {
    "data_from": "first_file"
  },
  {
    "data_from": "second_file"
  }
]
```

I tried:
jq -s . file1 file2

But the result is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "data_from": "first_file"
    }
  ]
  ,
  [
    {
      "data_from": "second_file"
    }
  ]
]
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: are there only 2 input files?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear from the question what the expected output is supposed to be, but it looks like you want to concatenate the arrays.

If that's the case and if your file list is file1 file2 ... then the following invocation would be appropriate:

```
jq add file1 file2 ...
```

p.s. In future, please follow the guidelines at  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal complete verifiable example

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found my solution on github: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/805#issuecomment-109783967

> Using the -s option will return an array containing the contents of the input JSON files, which, in your case, are also arrays. This means that you need to spread (…[]) two array levels, and collect ([…]) the result.

`jq -s '[.[][]]' a-*.json > manifest.json`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with:

`jq -s 'flatten' file1 file2 ...`

So -s (slurp) assembles an array of files' contents (arrays), and `flatten` removes the extra [] levels and the output is an array of all records from all files.